# Gcd of two expressions

Tags: number-theory

Given $$a(n) =n^2+20$$
Find the possible values of
$$\gcd( a(n), a(n+1) ).$$

I tried doing this and got that the $\gcd$ of both the numbers should divide $2n+1$,  but after this I am not able to get anything.

Comment: Put n=1 then gcd can be 3 please read the question.

Comment: @user3650050 For $n=3$, the GCD of $29$ and $36$ is most surely not $3$.

Comment: Sorry n=1 I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use $(\cdot,\cdot)$ to denote the gcd. We have

$$ (n^2+20, (n+1)^2 + 20) = (n^2 + 20, n^2 + 2n + 21) = (n^2 + 20, 2n+1),$$

where in the last step I've replaced the second number by the difference of the two (which you're allowed to do).

Now note that $2n+1$ is odd, so if I multiply $n^2 + 20$ by $4$ the gcd doesn't change:

$$\begin{align*}(n^2+20,2n+1)&=(4n^2+80, 2n+1) = ((2n+1)^2-4n+79,2n+1) \\&= (-4n+79, 2n+1),\end{align*}$$

where I've subtracted $(2n+1)$ times the second number from the first in the last step. Continuing we have:

$$ (-4n+79,2n+1) = (-4n+79+4n+2,2n+1) = (81,2n+1)$$

Therefore $$\gcd(a(n),a(n+1))=\min\{81, 3^k\},$$ where $3^k$ is the highest power of $3$ in the prime decomposition of $2n+1$.

Comment: I doubt your answer is correct. The $\max$ seems strange, it seems to imply that it is impossible to get a result under $81$, which is obviously untrue.

Comment: How did you come to such an awesome solution

Comment: @5xum: Erm I meant minimum sorry, will edit.

Comment: @user3650050: There's not too many ways to solve problems like this. They almost all involve reducing the two numbers step by step, mostly by subtracting a multiple of one from the other, until they're simple enough that you can read off the gcd.

Comment: Can you suggest some practice questions

Comment: The first few sections of any book on elementary number theory should have some relevant exercises. For example, see the problems after section 1.2 of *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Niven,  Zuckerman, and Montgomery.